# Tags missing when fetching from API filtered by dates

Tags: support, tags

I'm experimenting with the API, trying to get the tags used in the last month on Stack Overflow, and it seems like some tags are missing. For example, I don't get anything for "jquery":
http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#fromdate=2013-10-01&todate=2013-11-01&order=desc&sort=popular&inname=jquery&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

On the other hand, if I look here - https://stackoverflow.com/tags and put "jquery" in the "Type to find tags" field I get "401 asked today". The number obviously may differ based on the day, but it's certainly not zero for the entire month.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that for that route, `fromdate` and `todate` specify the range for the creation date of the tag (if they do anything at all, since tag creation information isn't usually made public anywhere) since they [always reflect the bounds of the `creation_date` field](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max).

Instead, for your use case, you should use the `activity` sort with the `min` and `max` parameters. This will give you the [tags with the substring jquery used within the given timeframe](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#order=desc&min=2013-10-01&max=2013-11-01&sort=activity&inname=jquery&filter=!9f8L72laL&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: Thanks Tim. I assumed "creation_date" refers to the creation of the questions... in question :) Also, seems like if I sort by the activity, it means that I have to page through all the results in order to get the most popular tags. Would you agree?

Comment: It would seem that way, yes, which admittedly isn't very ideal.